# For NxM array , Write a function such that if user input is (x,y) It should return a sum of all values from (0,0) to (x,y). where x<N & y<M

Tags: python, algorithm

I was stucks in question in between badly. Any suggestions? I tried below code:

```
def getSum(A, n, m, x, y):

    res = 0

    for row in range(n + 1):
        for col in range(m + 1):

            if col <= y: 
                res += A[row][col]

    return res
```

Comment: Is the use of numpy allowed?

Comment: No @Wade.. No library function please.

Comment: You have to specify clearly - what does `from (0,0) to (x,y)` mean. In any case, your code logic is flawed.

Comment: x is less than N and y is less than M.

Comment: You can do this using dynamic programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to iterate over the whole matrix in kind of "filter out" the values that you don't need. Instead of that, you should try to iterate only over the values that you need, which in this case is possible and not hard. With the rows you just need to go from row indices `0` to `x`, so you would use `for row in range(x + 1)`. For the columns, you would have to iterate through all of them (up to `m - 1`) for rows `0` to `x - 1` and only up to `y` for row index `x`. You can just compute that as `last_col = m - 1 if row < x else y` and then iterate like `for col in range(last_col + 1)`. Then you simply sum all the values that you iterate, since you do not need to "filter" any of them:

```
def getSum(A, n, m, x, y):

    res = 0

    for row in range(x + 1):
        last_col = m - 1 if row < x else y
        for col in range(last_col + 1):
            res += A[row][col]

    return res
```

Note: The `n` and `m` parameters are not really necessary in the function, I have kept them to maintain the same function prototype that you proposed, but if it is up to you to decide what parameters you need you would leave them out. Even if you needed them you could get them from `A` using `len`.

Note 2: I am only considering the problem of computing the result for a valid set of inputs. Remember that many times in this kind of tests the interviewer wants to check how you deal with bad inputs (negative numbers, invalid sizes, `None`, etc) and corner cases.

Note 3: If you want you could do everything in a single one-liner, although honestly it will probably be just harder to read and I am not sure an interviewer would appreciate that. You could also consider an intermediate option. In any case, the above function body could be condensed to:

```
return sum(sum(A[row][col] for col in range(m if row < x else y + 1)) for x in range(x + 1))
```

Comment: Thank you @jdehesa, But this will give the wrong result. suppose for (x,y) = (1,0) so it should give the sum of 1st row and 1st element of the 2nd row. Which your code wont give. right?

Comment: @CodeQuestor Oh I see, so you mean you need to sum the numbers from `(0, 0)` to `(x, y)` as if you were iterating through them row by row? If that is the case, could you please update the question to make it clearer, and maybe give an example?

Comment: @CodeQuestor I have updated the answer, please comment if it is still not the right solution.

Comment: It is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can improve this by creating another `NxM` matrix where the element at `(x, y)` would contain the sum of the elements from `(0, 0)` to `(x, y)` of the original matrix. Once you create this matrix, you can answer any query by just looking it up.

Now, there would be `MN` values to calculate. If you try to sum up all the values in the sub-matrix, It would take `O((MN))` time in worst case for each query. But with some memoization, it can be generated in `O(MN)` time using dynamic programming and then each query can be answered in `O(1)` time.

The solution relies on a simple recurrence relation (`S[x][y]` denotes the sum of elements of A from `(0, 0)` to `(x, y)`):

```
S[0, 0] = A[0, 0]
S[0, y] = S[0, y - 1] + A[0, y] when y > 0
S[x, 0] = S[x - 1, 0] + A[x, 0] when x > 0
S[x, y] = S[x, y - 1] + S[x - 1, y] - S[x - 1, y - 1] + A[x, y] when x, y > 0
```

The key point is, both of the sums of the sub-matrices from `(0, 0)` to `(x, y - 1)` and from `(0, 0)` to `(x - 1, y)` contain the sum of the sub-matrix from `(0, 0)` to `(x - 1, y -1)`, so we are adding it twice. That's why we need to subtract it once.

So the code for it should be simple:

```
def sumMatrix(A):
    S = [[0 for i in range(len(A[j]))] for j in range(len(A))]
    S[0][0] = A[0][0]

    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        S[i][0] = S[i - 1][0] + A[i][0]

    for j in range(1, len(A[0])):
        S[0][j] = S[0][j - 1] + A[0][j]

    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        for j in range(1, len(A[0])):
            S[i][j] = S[i][j - 1] + S[i - 1][j] - S[i - 1][j - 1] + A[i][j]

    return S
```

Once you call this method, you can answer any query in `O(1)` time by looking it up!

It can also be shortened a little bit:

```
def sumMatrix(A):
    S = [[A[i][j] for i in range(len(A[j]))] for j in range(len(A))]

    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        for j in range(0, len(A[0])):
            if i > 0:
                S[i][j] += S[i - 1][j]
            if j > 0:
                S[i][j] += S[i][j - 1]
            if i > 0 and j > 0:
                S[i][j] -= S[i - 1][j - 1]

    return S
```

Comment: Seems you have overcomplicated the solution (while question still is not quite clear)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand(20, 20)
list = array.tolist()


def get_sum_numpy(x, y):
    return np.sum(array[:x, :y])


def get_sum_list(x, y):

    total = 0

    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            total += list[i][j]

    return total


print(get_sum_numpy(4, 5))
print(get_sum_list(4, 5))
```

Here is a quick solution that I came up with. Using numpy is more efficient but there is a solution without a third part library as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] # a 3x3 Matrix
sum = 0
# entered string (3,1)
# calculating sum from (0,0) till the given
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(a[i])):
        if (i+1)>=3:
            if (j+1)>=1:
                break
        else:
            sum += a[i][j]
            print (a[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
getSum(A, n, m, x, y):
    if (x >= n):
        # x is out of bounds. Do some error handling here
    if (y >= m):
        # y is out of bounds. Do some error handling here

    return sum( [ sum(col[:y]) for col in A[:x] ] )
```

This uses a list comprehension to grab every row from A over indices 0 to x and then calculates the sum of each row from column 0 to y and calculates the sum of these sums.

As an aside, if you have already checked that `x < n` and `y < m` beforehand, you don't need to use these as arguments to your function.